# Android Same instance output different result

Tags: java, android

I outputted the same object at the same time but I got different results... 
What could be the cause of DIFFERENT result?

The function in UserHelper.class:

```
public void login(String phone, String password) {
    UserModel.logInInBackground(phone, password, new LogInCallback<UserModel>() {
        @Override
        public void done(UserModel userModel, AVException e) {
            if (null != userModel) {
                if (userModel.getPosition() == UserModel.USER_BUYER) {
                    refresh();
                    DebugLog.e("fuck" + mUserStatus + UserInstance.getInstance().getUserStatus());
                    for (UserListener listener : listeners)
                        listener.OnUserLogin();
                } else if (userModel.getPosition() == UserModel.USER_SELLER)
                    logout();
            } else for (UserListener listener : listeners)
                listener.HandleError(e.getCode());
        }
    }, UserModel.class);

public USER_STATUS getUserStatus() {
    return mUserStatus;
}
```

And the UserInstance.class.

```
public class UserInstance {
    public static UserHelper mInstance;

public static UserHelper getInstance() {
    if (null == mInstance) mInstance = new UserHelper();
    DebugLog.e(mInstance.toString());
    return mInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which objects exactly should be the same? mUserStatus and UserInstance.getInstance().getUserStatus()? And which class contains the login method?

Comment: yes
public USER_STATUS getUserStatus() {
        return mUserStatus;
    }

Comment: so `login(..)` is a method of the `UserHelper`?! Did you debug to the line, in which you logged the objects, to compare the object ids? I would need more code - where do you call the login-method?

Comment: Does your  UserModel.logInInBackground() runs in UI thread or separate thread ?

Comment: In the first Activity when user click login button I call the login-method. And I logged the objects it do have different ids but I do not know why...

Comment: runs in separate thread

Comment: Do you call `UserInstance.getInstance().login(..)` when the user clicks the button or do you create a new `UserHelper`?

Comment: call UserInstance.getInstance().login(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you meant the `UserHelper` class to be a singleton,
why do you access the `USER_STATUS` instance using `UserInstance.getInstance().getUserStatus()` instead of just `getUserStatus()` ?

Second of all, you probably get different instances of `UserHelper` if the singleton is accessed from different threads, because your implementation is not thread-safe.

A correct implementation would be using a [double locking pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking):

```
public class UserInstance {
    public static UserHelper mInstance;
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static UserHelper getInstance() {
        if (null == mInstance){
            lock.lock();
            try{
               if (null == mInstance){
                    mInstance = new UserHelper();
               }
            }
            finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        DebugLog.e(mInstance.toString());
        return mInstance;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I get the same instance..

Thanks to Shlomi Uziei. I forgot to use double locking pattern. And I should not make mInstance static...